Buyoancy with two liquids


A spherical ball of radius R is floating at the interface of two liquids with densities ρ and 2ρ. The volumes of the ball immersed in two liquids are equal.
Find the force exerted by the liquid with density 2ρ on the ball

If this liquid from above did not exist, it would be very easy to calculate the buoyancy, it would be the trivial case in all the books: $\rho V g$.
But there is a liquid on top, and this column of liquid on top will increase the pressure on the liquid below, causing the buoyancy of the liquid below to be greater.
My question is not about the answer or solution to the question, but rather a question about how the liquid column at the top will increase the pressure in the liquid below.
Because the liquid from above is actually pushing the sphere down.

I guess it could be average of two buoyancies, i.e. $$\frac{g \frac 12 V \rho_1 + g \frac 12 V \rho_2 }{2}$$. If ball is immersed into a fluid which continuously changes it's density going up per $dr$ sphere layer, then you would probably need some sort of integration procedure, like $ \int_0^R g~ \rho(r)~ 4/3 \pi r^2 dr$.

The density of each liquid is constant.

I mean technically you can have some liquid mixture which monotonically  changes density going up, i.e. infinite number of liquid layers with different densities. I just abstracted your problem into more general one. But in your specific case probably to calculate average of pair buoyancies is enough.
